# How to mock a base class with python mock library

Tags: python, mocking

I try to use `mock` to write some unit-tests in python.

For example I have the following class:

```
class TCPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
```

And I only want to test the `handle` method. Without having to assume anything about `socketserver.BaseRequestHandler`. I for example want to assert that `handle` calls `recv` with the argument `1024`. Is it possible to do such thing with mock? I.e. replacing the base class `socketserver.BaseRequestHandler` with a mock? Or am I off track with that idea?

---

With the answer of ecatmur (thank you!) I first tried the following:

```
patcher = patch.object(TCPHandler, '__bases__', (Mock,))
with patcher:
    patcher.is_local = True
    handler = TCPHandler()
    handler.handle()
```

But now `handle` is not called anylonger and `dir(handler)` gives:

```
['assert_any_call', 'assert_called_once_with', 'assert_called_with', 'assert_has_calls', 'attach_mock', 'call_args', 'call_args_list', 'call_count', 'called', 'configure_mock', 'method_calls', 'mock_add_spec', 'mock_calls', 'reset_mock', 'return_value', 'side_effect']
```

`type(handler)` gives
   `<class 'mock.TCPHandler'>`

Which I interpret that patching the base class also turns my derived class into a mock.

---

I now gave another idea a try:

```
mock = MagicMock()
TCPHandler.handle(mock)
#assertions
```

However the mock seems not to be called.

Comment: For anyone hitting the first google result: I just had the same issue with a smartcard reader. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28666122/3303749) from robru to be a functional solution.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can do this by patching the derived class's `__bases__`:

```
def test_derived():
    patcher = mock.patch.object(Derived, '__bases__', (mock.Mock,))
    with patcher:
        patcher.is_local = True
        d = Derived()
        print d.foo()
```

The `is_local` hack is necessary to stop `mock.patch` from trying to call `delattr` when reversing the patch.

Comment: I followed your hint but the consequence was, that also the method of the derived class is replaced by the mock.

Comment: I put my current test code in the question, if you might have a look? I appreciate your help.

Comment: @FrederickRoth not too sure; it works fine for me with Python 2.  Perhaps try mocking the parts of the object that the method accesses?

Comment: I tested your idea with python 2.7 instead of python 3, now I get a type error: TypeError: __bases__ items must be classes.

Comment: @FrederickRoth ah, the problem in Python 2 is that socketserver.BaseRequestHandler is an old-style class.

Comment: OK, thanks anyway! I think your solution is a good one but unfortunately I can't really use it in my environment.

Comment: This sort of works for me in Python 3, in that the base class is replaced with a `Mock` object, but if the derived class tries to use `super()` to call a method on the base class, then it fails with `AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'foo'`.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if it is the best solution but I managed redefining the previous class with a different parent using [type()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type). I built a function called `patch_parent()`, that returns the class with a parent mock:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def patch_parent(class_):
    """
    Mock the bases
    """
    yield type(class_.__name__, (Mock,), dict(class_.__dict__))
```

After this, you can use the `patch_parent` like this:

```
class Bar():
   def method(self, param1, param2...):
       ...

class Foo(Bar):
   pass


>>> with patch_parent(Foo) as MockFoo:
...     f = MockFoo()
...     print f
...     print f.method()
... 
<Foo id='15488016'>
<Foo name='mock.method()' id='15541520'>
>>> s = Foo()
>>> s.method()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: method() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)
```

The `MockFoo` class still has the methods of the `Foo` class and it doesn't have the methods defined in the parent because the parent is now a  `Mock` class.

Comment: This fails for me if `Foo` has a non-trivial `__init__` - and in particular if it attempts `super().__init__()`.  Failure is `TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type`.

Answer (score 6):

I think the problem is really that you are trying to mock the actual code you want to test. Rather than the objects that are being called by that code. If you are interested in seeing whether the handle method calls the recv method on self.request then mock out the recv method.

```
def test_tcp_handler_method(self):

    handler = TCPHandler()
    handler.request = Mock()

    handler.handle()

    self.assertTrue(handler.request.recv.called)
    self.assertEqual(handler.request.recv.call_args[0], 1024)
```

You might have to do some extra setup in order to get handler to instantiate but the basic idea should be clear.

Comment: Thanks for your input! The TCPHandler needs a tcprequest to instantiate and therefore is never instantiated directly by my code, but by a TCPServer. This is the whole reason why I don't want to call its `__init__`. I just want to test my own small method without also testing the whole tcpserver framework.

Comment: @FrederickRoth you can mock out the TCPServer as a whole this way. It is a much clearer syntax than the accepted answer.