# Python mock: mocking base class for inheritance

Tags: python, unit-testing, inheritance, mocking

I am testing a class that inherits from another one very complex, with DB connection methods and a mess of dependences. I would like to mock its base class so that I can nicely play with the method defined in the subclass, but in the moment I inherit from a mocked class, the object itself turns a mock and loses all its methods.

**How can I mock a superclass?**

More or less the situation can be summed up in this:

```
import mock

ClassMock = mock.MagicMock()

class RealClass(ClassMock):

    def lol(self):
        print 'lol'

real = RealClass()
real.lol()  # Does not print lol, but returns another mock

print real # prints <MagicMock id='...'>
```

This is a simplified case. What is actually happening is that `RealClass` extends `AnotherClass`, but I managed to intercept the `AnotherClass` and replace it with a mock.

Comment: Do you really need a Mock object as the base class? Would a simple `object` work?

Comment: What is MagicMock? a class or a class generator? Normally you would just `class RealClass(mock.MagicMock):`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
import mock

ClassMock = mock.MagicMock # <-- Note the removed brackets '()'

class RealClass(ClassMock):

    def lol(self):
        print 'lol'

real = RealClass()
real.lol()  # Does not print lol, but returns another mock

print real # prints <MagicMock id='...'>
```

You should'nt pass an instance of the class as you did. `mock.MagicMock` is a class, so you pass it directly.

```
In [2]: inspect.isclass(mock.MagicMock)
Out[2]: True
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I was trying to do, but maybe it was just impossible: I was expecting to have a mock for the base class and then be able to tell what calls were done to the mock part of the object. The "drawback" of this approach is if the subclass overwrites the MagicMock methods. Anyway this works like a charm. Thanks

Comment: I got a new problem with this approach. What if I want to call a class method `RealClass.do_something` that is supposed to be defined in the base class? since MagicMock is not a mock itself but a class, you can't add magically new methods to it :S

Comment: took me a moment to figure out what the difference was here.. to help others, the difference is ClassMock = mock.MagicMock vs. ClassMock = mock.MagicMock()

Answer (score 22):

This is something I've been struggling with for a long time, but I think I've finally found a solution.

As you already noticed, if you try to replace the base class with a Mock, the class you're attempting to test simply becomes the mock, which defeats your ability to test it. The solution is to mock only the base class's methods rather than the entire base class itself, but that's easier said than done: it can be quite error prone to mock every single method one by one on a test by test basis.

What I've done instead is created a class that scans another class, and assigns to itself `Mock()`s that match the methods on the other class. You can then use this class in place of the real base class in your testing.

Here is the fake class:

```
class Fake(object):
    """Create Mock()ed methods that match another class's methods."""

    @classmethod
    def imitate(cls, *others):
        for other in others:
            for name in other.__dict__:
                try:
                    setattr(cls, name, Mock())
                except (TypeError, AttributeError):
                    pass
        return cls
```

So for example you might have some code like this (apologies this is a little bit contrived, just assume that `BaseClass` and `SecondClass` are doing non-trivial work and contain many methods and aren't even necessarily defined by you at all):

```
class BaseClass:
    def do_expensive_calculation(self):
        return 5 + 5

class SecondClass:
    def do_second_calculation(self):
        return 2 * 2

class MyClass(BaseClass, SecondClass):
    def my_calculation(self):
        return self.do_expensive_calculation(), self.do_second_calculation()
```

You would then be able to write some tests like this:

```
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        MyClass.__bases__ = (Fake.imitate(BaseClass, SecondBase),)

    def test_my_methods_only(self):
        myclass = MyClass()
        self.assertEqual(myclass.my_calculation(), (
            myclass.do_expensive_calculation.return_value, 
            myclass.do_second_calculation.return_value,
        ))
        myclass.do_expensive_calculation.assert_called_once_with()
        myclass.do_second_calculation.assert_called_once_with()
```

So the methods that exist on the base classes remain available as mocks you can interact with, but your class does not itself become a mock.

And I've been careful to ensure that this works in both python2 and python3.

Comment: Great answer. I improved you class `Fake` by using `setattr(cls, name, mock.create_autospec(other.__dict__[name]))` instead of `setattr(cls, name, Mock())` to improve safety and add some more testing abilities.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing a similar problem and was able to do this via `@patch.object`. See examples for [patch decorators](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html#patch-decorators) in the official python doc.

```py
class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch.object(SomeClass, 'inherited_method')
    def test_something(self, mock_method):
        SomeClass.static_method()
        mock_method.assert_called_with()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just exemplifying @[Akash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7036012/akash)'s answer, which was the one that in fact solved my inheritance mock challenge:

```
 @patch.object(SomeClassInheritingAnother, "inherited_method")
    def test_should_test_something(self, mocked_inherited_method, mocker, caplog):
       #Mocking an HTTP result status code
       type(mocked_inherited_method.return_value).status_code = mocker.PropertyMock(return_value=200)

       #Calling the inherited method, that should end up using the mocked method
       SomeClassInheritingAnother.inherited_method()

       #Considering that the request result is being logged as 'Request result: {response.status_code}'
       assert "Request result: 200" in caplog.text
```