# How to mock a base_class from an external module?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm trying to unit test a class which is derived from a base_class in an external module. In my dev/test environment I have not access to this external module, which means I have to somehow mock this base_class.

My test-code resides in a different file from the code I'm trying to test.

The problem can be summarized as follows:

**my_class.py**

```py
import external_module

class MyClass(external_module.ExternalClass):
    def test_method(self):
        return "successful"
```

**test_my_class.py**

```py
import sys
import unittest
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

sys.modules['external_module'] = MagicMock()

from my_class import MyClass

class TestMyClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_first(self):
        my_class = MyClass()
        result = my_class.test_method()
        self.assertEqual(result, "successful")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

### Results

---

When running test_my_class.py the result are the following.

```
AssertionError: <MagicMock name='mock.ExternalClass.test_method()' id='140272215184664'> != 'successful'
```

Clearly since the external_module is mocked, even MyClass becomes an instance of a mock-object.

### Similar posts

---

The problem is similar to as described in [Python mock: mocking base class for inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817511/python-mock-mocking-base-class-for-inheritance/28666122), but has the difference that the base_class is from an external module.

Even [How to mock a base class with python mock library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219967/how-to-mock-a-base-class-with-python-mock-library) show som similarities to my problem, though the solutions can not be directly applied.

### Tries and failures

---

To get the import

```py
import external_module
```

to work in **my_class.py**

```py
sys.modules['external_module'] = MagicMock()
```

need to be set in **test_my_class.py**.

Though, this leads to that external_module.* becomes a Mock-instance.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a helper module `mocked_external_module`, which can be imported from your tests and also contains a class `base_class`.  Then you do the following in your test code:

```
import mocked_external_module
sys.modules['external_module'] = mocked_external_module
```

Plus, every method of your `base_class` that you need to mock you can create as a Mock or MagicMock.