# How to import/decorate patched classes correctly in python 3.x

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, mocking

I want to test a custom child class of http.server.CGIHTTPRequestHandler. As the **init** method and all other methods of CGIHTTPRequestHandler do a lot of irrelevant stuff for my tests I want to mock it. But I don't get how to achieve that by decorating the setUp-method of my tests with @patch.
I don't get howto import/decorate a patched class correctly, so I created a minimal example:

```
/src/samplepackage/
   tests/
      __init__.py
      sutclass_tests.py
   __init__.py
   parentclass.py
   sutclass.py
```

parentclass.py:

```
class ParentClass():

    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        print("__init__ doing much to much stuff with " + str(a) + " " + str(b) + " " + str(c))
```

sutclass.py:

```
from samplepackage.parentclass import ParentClass

    class SUTClass (ParentClass):

    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d):
        super().__init__(a, b, c)
        self.sutAttribute = d

    def SUTmethod(self):
        self.sutAttribute = self.sutAttribute * 2
        return self.sutAttribute
```

sutclass_tests.py:

```
import unittest
from samplepackage.sutclass import SUTClass
from unittest.mock import patch
class SUTClassTests(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch("samplepackage.sutclass.SUTClass.Parent.__init__")
    def setUp(self):
        unittest.TestCase.setUp(self)
        self.sutClass = SUTClass(1,2,3,4)

    def test_firstIteration(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.sutClass.SUTmethod(), 8)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Executing the sutclass_tests.py results in:

```
============================= ERRORS =============================
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/mock.py", line 1149, in patched
    arg = patching.__enter__()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/mock.py", line 1205, in __enter__
    self.target = self.getter()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/mock.py", line 1375, in <lambda>
    getter = lambda: _importer(target)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/mock.py", line 1062, in _importer
    thing = _dot_lookup(thing, comp, import_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/mock.py", line 1051, in _dot_lookup
    __import__(import_path)
ImportError: No module named 'samplepackage.sutclass.SUTClass'; 'samplepackage.sutclass' is not a package
```

I get that 'samplepackage.sutclass' is not a package (didn't intent to use it as a package). Changing the @patch-decorator to

```
@patch("samplepackage.SUTClass.Parent.__init__")
```

yields:

```
============================= ERRORS =============================
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/mock.py", line 1049, in _dot_lookup
    return getattr(thing, comp)
AttributeError: module 'samplepackage' has no attribute 'SUTClass'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/mock.py", line 1149, in patched
    arg = patching.__enter__()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/mock.py", line 1205, in __enter__
    self.target = self.getter()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/mock.py", line 1375, in <lambda>
    getter = lambda: _importer(target)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/mock.py", line 1062, in _importer
    thing = _dot_lookup(thing, comp, import_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/mock.py", line 1051, in _dot_lookup
    __import__(import_path)
ImportError: No module named 'samplepackage.SUTClass'
```

So my question is howto patch the parent class (ParentClass) of my SUTClass in the setUp-method (as I want to reuse it in muliple testcases) correctly?

Comment: Which line is raising the `ImportError`?

Comment: @Goyo added the complete stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

I found [How to mock a base class with python mock library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219967/how-to-mock-a-base-class-with-python-mock-library) which solves my issue. Though not by decoration but by `mock.patch.object()`.
I changed `sutclass_tests.py` to:

```
import unittest
from samplepackage.sutclass import SUTClass
from unittest.mock import patch
from unittest import mock
class SUTClassTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        unittest.TestCase.setUp(self)
        patcher = patch.object(SUTClass, '__bases__', (mock.Mock,))
        with patcher:
            patcher.is_local = True
            self.sut = SUTClass(1,2,3,4)

    def test_firstIteration(self):       
        print(self.sut.SUTmethod())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

This solves my problem (no import errors) and shows the correct behaviour when testing my real scenario with my class derived from `http.server.CGIHTTPRequestHandler`